# Import a csv file from desktop into Pycharm (on Mac)

Tags: python, csv, import, pycharm

I have trouble importing a csv file from my desktop into my Project folder in Pycharm. I would like to have this csv file in the same directory inside Pycharm.

I tried PyCharm->Project Structure->+Add content root,   but it's not working.

Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy and paste the csv file into the desired folder within the PyCharm project navigation window. Then you can use this code to open the file:

```
file = open("path to file here", "r")
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment Nathaniel. But I would like to have the file inside Pycharm under the same directory and access it like: file=open("file_name", "r")

Comment: You can do just that by copying and pasting the file within the same directory in the PyCharm project navigation window.